# Is there a way to manipulate lcd backlight in android?

Tags: android

In my application, I need to change the screen backlight for testing. I am atm using API 15 with the external jar Hardware09.jar which has a method called setScreenBacklight(int value).

However when I tried to use it I have an error message like this:

```
01-01 00:48:24.570: E/AndroidRuntime(2171): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.IHardwareService.setScreenBacklight
```

I dont know what to do in that situation. Is there a way to use that external jar or are there any other ways to control backlight?

Thanks in advance.

This is the screenshot of java build path.

[image]

Comment: Have you imported properly your `.jar` file?

Comment: Yes, importing is done properly. But got that error on run time.

Comment: May i see the screenshot of your (project -> properties -> java build path -> order tab) ?

Comment: I added the screenshot to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float BackLightValue = (float)value/100; //value is the integer that test station pass to apk

WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.screenBrightness = BackLightValue;
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

Using that block of code, I manage to manipulate backlight. However I am currently thinking that way wont actually manipulate backlight rather screen brightness.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is the problem. This because of the additional jar files are not properly added to your project. Please remind below things -

- If you want to use any external jar file. You should have that in your project's `libs` folder properly.
- Should properly import that is another thing. And the important thing is , in your `project's -> properties -> java build path -> order tab` Should have the imported jar file.
- Should tick that jar file and have to place to order in first. Then, only you can use the `.jar` file.

This is common thing for all the `.jar` file which is manually imported. Try above steps.

Comment: I place the external jar file in first order as u said but still got the same error.

Comment: [Are you trying to do like this](http://openintents.googlecode.com/files/Flashlight-1.1.apk)

Comment: let me check it. But what I actually trying to do is making a test apk for a tablet. In that test apk I need to change backlight level.

Comment: I will set backlight brightness according the some test cases. And I stopped working with IHardwareService jar since it doesnt seem to be fixed. I implemented a new apk that works with WindowManager.LayoutParams screenBrightness value since I found on web that setting its value also effect backlight brightness.

Comment: @denizt Good to hear this. Better post an answer by yourself and accept it.

Comment: well actually it was someones answer for my question. I tried his way and changed 1 or 2 things and manage to manipulate backlight. ( I suppose I am doing it right since when I set its value to 0 light on LCD screen totally disappears.)